# Delete sublists by a numerical criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to use `DeleteCase` function but I don't know how to implement it in the way I need.

I have a list of sublists of numbers, for example:

```
{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,2},{4,2,5,1},{5,3,2,4}}
```

and I want to do is to delete all the sublists that contains an element greater than $4$.

The result would be like this:

```
{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,2}}
```

I am also avoiding loops or recursion.

Comment: Look up `Condition` and `Max`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 list = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 5, 1}, {5, 3, 2, 4}};    
 Select[list, Max[##] < 4 &]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 5, 1}, {5, 3, 2, 4}}; 

Pick[#, UnitStep[4 - Max /@ # ], 1] & @ lst
Pick[#, LessEqualThan[4] /@ Max /@ #]& @ lst 
Cases[lst, _?(Max @ # <= 4 &)]
DeleteCases[lst, _?(Max @ # > 4 &)]
Select[lst, Composition[LessEqualThan[4], Max]]
```

all give

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[list, AllTrue[# <= 4 &]], True]

(*{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}*)
```

Using `GatherBy`:

```
GatherBy[list, AllTrue[# <= 4 &]][[1]]

(*{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}*)
```

Using `ReplacePart` and `Position`:

```
ReplacePart[list, Position[list, {___, a_, ___} /; a > 4] -> Nothing]

(*{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}*)
```

Using `SplitBy`:

```
SplitBy[list, AllTrue[# <= 4 &]][[1]]

(*{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added a sublist: `{1,2,3,4}` to the test cases which should be selected according to criterion stated in the OP.

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 5, 1}, {5, 3,
    2, 4}}

DeleteCases[{___, a_, ___} /; a > 4][list]
DeleteCases[_?(AnyTrue[# > 4 &])][list]
Pick[list, FreeQ[_?(# > 4 &)] /@ list]
Pick[list, NoneTrue[# > 4 &] /@ list]
Pick[list, AllTrue[# <= 4 &] /@ list]
Select[AllTrue[# <= 4 &]][list]
Select[NoneTrue[# > 4 &]][list]
DeleteCases[list, _?(Or @@ 
     IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{5, ∞}], #] &)]
```

*Result:*

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

---

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 5, 1}, {5, 3, 2, 4}};
```

Using `Position` and `Delete`

```
p = List @* First /@ Position[list, x_ /; x > 4]
```

{{3}, {4}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}